# python won't update globals from imported function

Tags: python, global

I wrote a script to parse arguments from the command line.  It has a function called `getFlags` which parses `sys.argv` and a command string from the user to create a dictionary called `myVars` with the variable name and associated values, and returns the dictionary.  If I include the function in the main script I can move those variables to the globals() list by simply doing `globals().update(myVars)` inside the function.

However, when I save this function and import it, the update function does not work and I am forced to use `globals().update(getFlags(...))`.  This works fine for me but confuses some people who use my script.

How can I make it update the globals using the imported function?

**Example**

```
def getFlags(commandString,usage="No usage was provided"):
   ....
   globals().update(myVars)
   return myVars


getFlags("...")

#My variables are now in the global scope
```

```
from myScripts import getFlags

getFlags("...") 
#Oh no, variables not in global scope
globals().update(getFlags("...")
#Now the variables are in the global scope
```

Comment: I would definitely be confused if a function I called introduced even one variable into the global scope, let alone a bunch of them. Just return a dictionary and don't muck with the global scope like you're supposed to; everyone who uses this tool will thank you.

Comment: You may be interested in [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108) and [What are the pros and cons in use of global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484635/11082165). This looks like a really bad use case for global variables. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just explicitly pass information to and from functions instead of relying on some hidden state?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo But would you be confused if that is how the program told you it would work?  Mostly I made it that way to be compliant with similar programs I wrote in languages that only really use one scope, but I am aware of the confusion that scopes can cause in Python.

Comment: @jeffpkamp I'm going to guess you're talking about, maybe, MATLAB? I've heard that argument used to justify a lot of Python atrocities. "This is how I would do it in X" is *not* a justification for doing the same in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the name, the global namespace is not just one thing. There are separate global namespaces for each module. When code is run, it uses the global namespace for the module it was written in.

This is why the `globals.update` call you make in `getFlags` doesn't work as you want. It updates the global namespace of the `myScripts` module, rather than the global namespace of the calling code.

You could probably use `inspect` to walk the stack frames and find the global namespace of the caller, but I strongly suspect that it is not worth it. Adding stuff to a module's global namespace, especially with user-supplied data seems like a really bad idea. What if it redefined one of your functions? Or a builtin, like `list` or `print`?

Comment: Thank You.  I figured it was something like this, but couldn't find any documentation on it.  Now that you explained it I am finding documentation on it.  

This is a pretty standard argument parser, and like any other tool in Python (or any language for that matter) you can use it in incorrect ways with unexpected and undesirable results.   Kind of like the global scope :)

Comment: Looking into this more, I'm curious how the `__builtins__` module variables appear to be in the global scope, even though they are in the `__builtins__` scope.  I missed the object behavior of my module because I was using the `from module import method` approach, so the module wasn't visible in the global scope.